# Does someone have good tips on becoming a better programmer

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to ask a non-technical problem: I graduated from university nearly 2 years ago, and now I am facing a lot of questions.

First, how to improve my skills on programming? I know that writing code is the probably best method, but I find that if I am not familiar with a programming language and its libraries I can't write code fluently - I end up feeling that it's a waste of time.

Secondly, I have found a lot of books, about 50-60, but I have no time to read them!I am a little worried about missing some important knowledge.

Thirdly, after nearly two years of experience at work, I think I know what kind of programming skills I want to learn: android, Java EE, python and linux. However, there are so many things that I need to learn, it becomes a pressure and feels like a mess.

Can someone help me solve these problems? That would be a great help to me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: start reading now. no shortcuts.

Comment: There are no shortcuts to learning and never will be unless scientists invent some kind of medicine which will inject knowledge in brain. So you have to read, lean and then practice. That is the only way :)

Comment: You won't become fluent in something unless you keep doing it. Yes, you *are* wasting time in the beginning in the sense that somebody with more experience could do it faster. But you will never get the experience and hence become faster unless you *experience programming*. Which simply is slow in the beginning.

Comment: If you want to learn how to program, you have to invest time in it or let someone else do it. Period.

Comment: @L-Three I don't think you can learn programming by letting someone else do it... ;-P

Comment: @deceze what I meant was, if you don't want to invest time in it, let someone else do it and don't learn to program yourself. It's about priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is really rather off topic for this website, some thoughts:

1. Big skills are learned in little steps. So don't worry about learning everything, learn one thing and get better at it.
2. Set yourself reasonable challenges. Think of something you'd love to be able to do that's just beyond what you can do now, and learn how to do that.
3. Make the things you learn as much fun as possible.
4. When yo come up against a specific problem you can't find an answer to on the web, don;t worry, that's normal. Post your code and a specific question here and someone will try and help you learn that particular point.

All the best!

Comment: Thank you very much,your advice is pretty good,maybe I am so hasty that I can't learn programming well,it seems that I need to spend most of my daily time studying it patiently.

Comment: Write code, learn from the errors, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

[Learn Android programming](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) Step through the basics and you'll get a better feel for the big picture.

Comment: Thanks,I am just a little mess,when I study so match things at same time.

Comment: I was in the same position 4 years ago. You must just start at one point and work from there. Android programming is also going to teach you about doing XML layouts, CSS and user interface design. A bonus is that you're also learning Java and the XML is very much similar to XAML and other XML-based GUI languages.